# Snowpack custom build file name, like rollup

Tags: rollup, snowpack

[rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) has a feature that allows for a custom output file name.
in the rollup.config.js file you can do this:

```js
import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
  output: [{
    file: `build/${pkg.name}.browser.${pkg.version}.min.js`,
  }],
};
```

Let's say `package.json` includes `"name": "test-package", "version": "1.1.2"`
Running `rollup -c` produces the following output file:

```sh
build/test-package.browser.1.1.2.min.js
```

This is great for automating builds.
Does [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) offer something similar? [It uses rollup internally](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#packageoptionsrollup) so it could be possible, but I haven't been able to find a way of doing it in the documentation yet.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No I haven't, but I haven't looked again for a few months now. I ended up switching back to rollup.